# How do I copy contents of a row into a new sheet based on a certain criteria?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, vba

```
(A1) Date   (B1)RMA   Created By    (C1)Item Code... (I1)Resell?...
```

Now I1 has a dropdown with options "Yes" and "No"

If I1 has a value "YES" how do I copy the whole entire row (A2:M2) into the next sheet called "RMA Re-Sell Items"

I have tried using "if" functions but am having trouble with it.

Answer (score 1):

- Filter the data on column I, value Yes using the autofilter
- Select the filtered data
- Copy
- Paste onto the next sheet

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I would like for this to be done automatically, each time a Yes response it selected.

Comment: In a google spreadsheet, you can use QUERY() formula on the second sheet that 'copies' those rows. E.g: =query('Sheet1'!A1,I, "select * where I='Yes' ", 1). Note that will not delete the row from sheet 1. If you want that you will need a script.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the attached in the sheet module of your entry sheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

If Not Intersect(Columns("I"), Target) Is Nothing Then

    If Intersect(Columns("I"), Target.EntireRow) = "Yes" Then

        Target.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("RMA Re-Sell Items").Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow

    End If

End If

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, but is there a way to add the function to delete the column if user selects "No"

Comment: Also do you know how to copy this over into Google Doc Spreadsheet, it works in excel but i'm unfamiliar with placing it in google doc. Thanks again I really do appreciate all your help.

Comment: this will not work in google docs. It's a whole different language

Comment: If it's no, you want the whole row deleted?

Comment: Say a user accidentally chooses yes, then switches his response to no. I would like if the created line is deleted on the other sheet, not the original sheet. You mention this isn't compatible with Google Doc, do you know of a macro or function to replicate this within google doc.

Comment: for that, you'd run a `.find ` or a loop on the destination sheet, match any sort of unique id, then delete.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with this, outside of my expertise

Answer (score 0):

Ive figured it out using =FILTER( 'RMA FILE '!A:M ;  'RMA FILE '!I:I="Yes" ) but the problem I have now is this function then sorts it by date where as I want it to be sorted by the the row that was last added.

Example of current application with this function which sorts automatically by date:

```
11-11-12 ABC ABC ... ...
11-12-12 ....  ... .. ..
11-13-12 ... ... ... ..
```

I would like the range to be sorted by last added, if the user selects "Yes" on "RMA File" sheet I would like it to be sorted by that, whichever was last selected as "Yes", should then go to the bottom, not based on date.